# How may we reload struct pointer to array back to uint8_t array?

Tags: c, arrays, struct

Given struct

```
struct media{
     uint32_t addressOfPtr; 
 };
```

and in main()

```
uint8_t *msg_Ptr = NULL;
```

// given data is already populated afterwards in msg_Ptr

```
for (i=0; i < SIZE_MAX; i++)  // message fixed at length 10
    printf(" > %d",  msg_Ptr[i]);


struct media mediaObject2;
(mediaObject2.addressOfPtr) = malloc(SIZE_MAX*sizeof(uint8_t));
(mediaObject2.addressOfPtr) = (uint32_t) msg_Ptr;

functionB (&mediaObject2);
```

// how may we reload it in the array buffer uint8_t message[SIZE_MAX]?

```
void functionB (void* mediaObject) {

int i = 0;
// designate the structure / form of data to be loaded onto
uint8_t message[SIZE_MAX];
uint8_t* message_Ptr;

message_Ptr = (uint8_t*) media_ptr->addressOfPtr; // ->addressOfPtr

printf("Data that arrived in function B: \n");
for (i=0; i < SIZE_MAX; i++)  // message fixed at length 10
    printf(" %x",  ((uint8_t*) media_ptr->addressOfPtr)[i]);

printf("\n");

    // how to load back in uint8_t message[SIZE_MAX] ?


}
```

Comment: What is all this? Can you please get rid of the *messages* and *media objects* and shorten the example into something understandable? Also, try to describe what you want to better, *reloading a pointer back into an array* doesn't make sense.

Comment: The data has arrived in functionB.
How do we load the data into uint8_t message[SIZE_MAX]?

Comment: [`memcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy) it?

Comment: Thank you, @Praetorian. I tried 2 methods. memcpy() as well.
Thank you very much. I am grateful.

memcpy(message, ((uint8_t*) media_ptr->addressOfPtr), SIZE_MAX);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying memcpy, but this is 1 way that works.

```
for (i=0; i < SIZE_MAX; i++)  {// message fixed at length 10
    //printf(" %x",  ((uint8_t*) media_ptr->addressOfPtr)[i]);
    message[i] = ((uint8_t*) media_ptr->addressOfPtr)[i];
    printf(" %x",  message[i]);
}
```